# Collapse regular time periods data based on class keeping time order

Tags: r, dplyr, timestamp, vectorization

This question is closely related to my previous post in the following link:
[Expand periods to regularly occuring timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51551264/expand-periods-to-regularly-occuring-timestamps)

Essentially, this is the reverse step for that question.

I now have a data set regularly spaced in time (1-min periods) and I need to collapse the periods so that each row represent a time period where the class remain constant as follows:

[image]

The sample input data frame is:

```
df_in <- tibble(st =seq(ymd_hms("2016-01-01 00:35:00"),
                         ymd_hms("2016-01-01 00:58:00")-60,60),
                 en = st+59)
df_in$cl <- c("a",rep("c",3),rep("a",6),rep("c",9),rep("a",1),"c",rep("b",2))
```

I managed to accomplish this via a loop as shown in the code below, but this is incredibly inefficient and slow (my data source is in the millions of rows).  I am sure there is a verctorised way of doing this via dplyr, and I hope someone can point me in the right direction:

```
df_in$flag <- 1
df_in %>% 
  mutate(flag = ifelse(lag(cl)==cl,0,1)) -> df_in

df_in$flag[1] <- 1
df_in$flag2 <- 0
df_in$flag2[1] <- 1

for (i in 2:nrow(df_in)) {
  if (df_in$flag[i] == 0) {
    df_in$flag2[i] = df_in$flag2[i-1]
  } else {
    df_in$flag2[i] = df_in$flag2[i-1] + 1
  }
}

df_in %>% 
  group_by(flag2) %>%
  summarise(st = min(st),
            en = max(en),
            cl = unique(cl)) %>% 
View()
```

Again thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df_in)[, .(st = min(st), en = max(en)), by = .(cl, idx = rleid(cl))]
#   cl idx                  st                  en
#1:  a   1 2016-01-01 00:35:00 2016-01-01 00:35:59
#2:  c   2 2016-01-01 00:36:00 2016-01-01 00:38:59
#3:  a   3 2016-01-01 00:39:00 2016-01-01 00:44:59
#4:  c   4 2016-01-01 00:45:00 2016-01-01 00:53:59
#5:  a   5 2016-01-01 00:54:00 2016-01-01 00:54:59
#6:  c   6 2016-01-01 00:55:00 2016-01-01 00:55:59
#7:  b   7 2016-01-01 00:56:00 2016-01-01 00:57:59
```

We set `st` equal to `min(st)` and `en` equal to `max(en)` by `cl` and `idx = rleid(cl)`. `rleid` creates a "run-length type id column".

---

With `dplyr` you could do

```
library(dplyr)
df_in %>% 
  mutate(idx = data.table::rleid(cl)) %>% 
  group_by(cl, idx) %>% 
  summarise(st = min(st),
            en = max(en)) %>% 
  arrange(idx) %>% 
  select(-idx)
```

Comment: Thanks @markus.  That's exactly what I needed.  Moreover, you introduced me to rleid and its different incarnations with different packages.